# JSON.parse not creating array on Ajax data retrieval

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

Calling an SP, via Ajax, that returns a string.

```
        var AjaxData = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;",    
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetHeartBeatData",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "JSON",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
        var MyTest = JSON.parse("[" + AjaxData + "]");
```

The SP returns what I'm expecting to see but when it goes "through Ajax" it comes back as

```
    AjaxData    "{"d":"[[\"Time\",\"DB1\",\"DB2\",\"DB3\",\"DB4\"],[\"1:00\",54,50,57,47],[\"2:00\",56,46,63,20],[\"3:00\",46,48,45,49],[\"4:00\",60,38,76,23],[\"5:00\",2,34,82,15],[\"6:00\",40,42,39,43],[\"7:00\",66,26,94,55],[\"8:00\",68,22,100,39],[\"9:00\",34,36,33,37],[\"10:00\",72,14,12,5],[\"11:00\",85,10,18,105],[\"12:00\",28,30,27,31],[\"13:00\",79,38,30,88],[\"14:00\",101,38,36,14],[\"15:00\",22,24,21,25],[\"16:00\",85,38,49,39],[\"17:00\",67,38,55,42],[\"18:00\",16,18,15,19],[\"19:00\",91,38,67,22],[\"20:00\",53,38,73,0],[\"21:00\",10,12,9,13],[\"22:00\",97,38,85,0],[\"23:00\",9,38,91,39]]"}"  String
```

When it executes the JSON.parse(AjaxData) it creates MyTest as an Array, except that the MyTest[0] element has a 'subcategory' of *proto* and d where MyTest[0].d is the data I'm looking for, but it's a string.  I'm feeding this into GoogleChart and GoogleChart expects an array.  How do I get the MyTest[0] element to be just the array in question?

Answer (score 2):

You are just one step away:

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(MyTest[0].d);
```

Comment: @user3821205 **Explanation:** You have a JSON string inside your JSON string, so you need to parse it twice. It's more likely that you want to fix the problem on the server so that the array does not get JSON encoded (as a string), then you would not need to parse it twice

Comment: The second JSON.parse(MyTest[0].d) returns "Syntax error"

I've managed to break it down into an array of strings with .split, but I still need an array of [sets of values] as opposed to an array of "[sets of values]"